# What is the practical data size limit for GKSession sendData:toPeers:withDataMode:error:?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gamekit

At what point should I break up an NSData object into multiple objects, or use a third party data source to send data between GKSession bluetooth peers?

Answer (score 5):

Found it in the GameCenter overview docs.  (Not sure why they don't put this right in the method docs, but oh well).

The recommendation is to keep it < 1000 bytes, with a limit of 86K.